# Class with two methods,can not be defined Python

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes, self

#Hello i made this program but something seems to not be ok.
Firstly i made it with one method "next_question" but i have to do it with two.
So i made calc_vathmo,when i did this i found some errors and i fixed some of them.
I tried with the static methods to fix the error but nothing happened,i also tried by using types module but again i did not make it.

```
name = input("name : ")
surname = input("surname : ")
print("hello " + name.rstrip('s ς S Σ') + " " + surname.rstrip('s ς S Σ'))
class Quiz: 
        def __init__(self,question,choice,right_answer,point):
            self.question = question
            self.choice = choice
            self.right_answer = right_answer
            self.point = point
    
        def next_question(self,ls_quest):
        
            for q in ls_quest:               
            
                choice_user = input(q.question).lower()
            
                x = True                   
        
                while x is True:
            
                    if choice_user not in q.choice:
                        x = True
                        print("try again.\n")
                        choice_user = input(q.question).lower()
                          
                    else:
                        x = False
                    
        def calc_vathmo(self,ls_erwt):
    
            score = 0                             
        
            if (self.choice_user != q.right_answer):             
                score = score - 1
                print("wrong!")
            else:
                score += q.point
                print("right!")

             if score < 0:             
                score = 0
            else:
                pass
        
            print("score " + name.rstrip('s ς S Σ') + " " + surname.rstrip('s ς S Σ')+ " is :  " + 
            str(score))

ls_erwt =  [Quiz("last char of word  ΄΄προγραμματισμός΄΄;\na.γ\nb.ς/σ\nc.α\nd.δ\n ",  
           ["a","b","c","d"],  "b" ,   3 ),
            Quiz("capital of greece;\na.Ναύπλιο\nb.Ηράκλειο\nc.Πάτρα\nd.Αθήνα\n ",        
           ["a","b","c","d"],  "d" ,   3 ),
            Quiz(" 5 + 5;\na.10\nb.5\nc.100\nd.0\n ",                                             
           ["a","b","c","d"],  "a" ,   3 ),
           ]

Quiz.next_question()
Quiz.calc_vathmo()


#Error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/laptopaki/Desktop/PYTHON TESTS/entest2.py", line 52, in <module>
    Quiz.next_question()
TypeError: Quiz.next_question() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'ls_quest'
```

That the error message

Comment: `Quiz.next_question()` passes neither `self` (because you're calling it on the _class_ not an instance) nor `ls_quest`. Why did you think that _would_ work?

Comment: You are attempting to call instance methods as class methods.  You need some list of questions as part of your class or a related class

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Learn to walk before you run. Keep it simple, get something basic defined and working.

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand few things here.

```
class Person:

    # init method is the first method that gets called when you create a new instance of the class
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    # now when you add self, it says that below function is a method of the class
    # and this function will be called on the instance of the class with the requred arguments.
    def some_class_method(self, greeting_message):
        print(greeting_message+ " " + self.name)

        
# now lets create a new instance of the class
person = Person("John")

# now lets' call the function on the instance of the class
person.some_class_method("Welcome")

# Output: Welcome John
```

what you are doing in your code, is putting instances in a list. and calling the `next_question` on your class instead of method of class.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the arguments in methods but i keep getting confused with the list.
I try to create the instance of the class by the way you told me

 `quiz = Quiz()` 

Now i have to pass 4 arguments because i have defined 4 in the init.But i dont know what to define.I want to pass somehow the list into the arguments.
Also,what arguments i have to pass when i call the methods?